# Gem Cocoon not rendering anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, cocoon-gem

I'm using Rails 6.0.2.2, Foundation, and wanted to do some nested forms using Cocoon. Here are my models:

```
class Adventure < ApplicationRecord
  alias_attribute :pcs, :player_characters

  has_many :player_characters, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :player_characters
end

class PlayerCharacter < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :adventure
end
```

And here my views:

```
# _form.html.erb

<%= simple_form_for @adventure do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :test %>
  <h3>PCs</h3>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :player_characters do |player_character| %>
      <%= render 'player_character_fields', f: player_character %>
    <% end %>
    <div class='links'>
      <%= link_to_add_association 'Add PC', f, :player_characters %>
    </div>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

# _player_character_fields.html.erb

<div class='nested-fields'>
  <%= f.input :path %>
  <%= f.input :race %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :player_name %>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove PC", f %>
</div>
```

Neither the `render` nor the `link_to` display anything. I tried creating a different partial and if I render it outside of the `simple_fields_for` it works normally, but as soon as  move it inside, it stops.
I tried all the solutions mentioned here https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/cocoon.js:

- create a file in `app/javascript/src/cocoon.js`
- `yarn add cocoon-js`
- `yarn add github:nathanvda/cocoon#c24ba53`

but nothing worked, and I didn't get any error messages in the console log.

Comment: This is weird, because neither the `render` or `link_to` are actually influenced by the way the js is included. So the render should work, _if_ there are any nested `player_characters`. A recurring error is that the `link_to_add_association` is placed inside the `fields_for` block, so it would also not be rendered if there are no nested items (but from your code here that does not seem the case).

Comment: any idea what I could try or other code I should share? the repo is public in case you want to check yourself https://github.com/Naokimi/kovarova_dcera/tree/cocoon

Comment: @nathanvda tried in another repo and it turns out the error comes from `accepts_nested_attributes_for`
when I uncomment or forget to write it, the form fields appear, but when I put it in, they disappear